# Error in Visual Studio CI/CD .Net Core Project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We faced lots of build errors on Visual Studio CI/CD for .net core project but this is our last error and we can't figure it out.
Our project is based on .net core v1.1 and the last error asked us to upgrade to .net core v2.0 and we did that.
All of the CI steps are succeed expect dotnet ef migrations:

This is error message:

> Method 'get_Properties' does not have an implementation. in type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.1.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Note: The project is building local machine and on Visual Studio CI

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not upgrade your solution successfully to .net core 2.x., since you're configuration is still depending on on a package from 1.1.

You should upgrade `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to 2.0 (2.1.1, if you're on .net core 2.1)

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration -version 2.0.0 -reinstall
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/